# make div load at bottom of screen in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to make a div load at the bottom of the user's screen. There are two situations i need to consider. If the body content of the page is less than the height of the user's screen, I need to dynamically figure out the height of user's screen so the footer will always be at the bottom of the screen.

Also if the body content is greater than the height of the screen the footer needs to be displayed after the body content has all been rendered.

TL:DR If the content of a page is smaller than the length of the window, the footer should be fixed at the bottom of the window. If it's not, the footer should display at the bottom of the content.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: `width: 100%, position: fixed, bottom: 0` except this will display over the body content at the bottom

Comment: Try to add: `left:0` and see if that works.

Comment: You can try `display: 'flex'; flexDirection: 'column-reverse'; height: '100%'` on the containing element